# Как синхронизировать данные в сессии с бд SQLalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, сессия, sqlalchemy

У меня есть два бота, сервисный и клиенсткий и я налаживаю комуникацю сервиса и клиента. Проблема заключается в том, что если один бот вносит изменения в бд, то второй их не видит до того, как я их не перезапущу, тоесть, не создам новое подключение. и поэтому возникает вопрос, как избавится от этой проблемыю БД- mysql

Comment: Вы случаем не забыли зафиксировать изменения при помощи “commit”?

Comment: я уже ответил на свой вопрос. Нашел сам решеине методом втыка. Подумал, а что если попробовать и получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session.commit() перед запросом на чтение обновит данные в сессии